# rails: displaying a user friendly message for a routing error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am working in rails 2.3 on mac osx leopard.
every time i type a url that does not exist in a rails application i get the following error

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/whatever_i_typed" with {:method=>:get}
```

this is find for development, but i was wondering how i can make sure users see a friendlier 'oops! not found' page. i was thinking about doing a begin...rescue block but i didn't know where to put it, not did i know the error code (i.e ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

thanks!
yuval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error will never appear in production.  Instead, users will see the public/404.html page.

To try this out on your localhost, put passenger/mongrel into production mode.  Override the `local_request?` method on your `ApplicationController` like so:

```
class ApplicationController
  def local_request?
    false
  end
end
```

If you'd like to experiment with dynamic behavior you can check out the `rescue_from` class method on ActionController.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
map.connect '*url', :controller => "not_found"
```

as a last `routes.rb` entry? I think it should do the trick, shouldn't it?

Comment: is there no way to 'rescue' the error like you would if you had an ActiveRecord error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the below url helpful for Rails 3.0.. users.

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution